# How to eliminate RTTI in sample code

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a k-d tree, which I think is good enough at this point. I've put the whole template at http://private.org.il/Code%20Projects/kd%20tree%20w%20bb%20cache.zipx

One thing I'd like to do is eliminate RTTI, and specifically calls to dynamic_pointer_cast.

_____________________ Edit with more info _____________________

The relevant part is that I use three classes: an abstract node class, that requires it's derived classes to implement the isInternal() function.

There are two classes that derive from it - an internal node class (function returns true), and a leaf node class (function returns false). Therefore, once isInternal is called, I know to which of the two derived classes the pointer can be casted to.

---

The one routine I'm having problem eliminating the call is ApproxNearestNeighborNode, which provides an initial guess for the nearest neighbor search. Currently it looks like this

```
shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> ApproxNearestNeighborNode(const kd_point &srcPoint) const
{
    unsigned int Depth = 0;
    shared_ptr<kd_node> Node(m_Root);

    while (Node->isInternal())
    {
        shared_ptr<kd_internal_node> iNode = dynamic_pointer_cast<kd_internal_node>(Node);

        if (srcPoint[Depth++%K] <= iNode->splitVal() || iNode->Right() == nullptr)
            Node = iNode->Left();
        else
            Node = iNode->Right();
    }

    shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> lNode = dynamic_pointer_cast<kd_leaf_node>(Node);

    return lNode;
}
```

The two issues that baffle me is keeping the routine iterative, rather than recursive, and returning a smart pointer to the leaf node.

[OK, I think there's a way to do it using shared_from_this, I just hope there's a way to do it rewriting as little code as possible.]

Any other feedback would be appreciated, but off topic, so please send it by email.

Comment: If you're sure that `kd_leaf_Node` inherits `kd_Node` you can do a `static_pointer_cast`.

Comment: _"Any other feedback would be appreciated, but off topic, so please send it by email."_ Huh?? We use comments for this.

Comment: So you expect people to download a proprietary WinZip format archive with all your code in order to make sense of the snippet posted? No. If you want help, post the minimal self-contained example, and if you want a code review, try the [CodeReview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1) It's 20KB for those who want to see the whole thing.

2) I wasn't familiar with CodeReview.se - will repost there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by πάντα ῥεῖ, [you can replace `dynamic_pointer_cast` by `static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast). It seems that your `Node->isInternal()` check is meant to ensure the dynamic case always succeeds, so a simple search-and-replace is enough.

Comment: Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ  & anatolyg!

The isInternal() is intended to allow me to know what node type the code encountered, and treat it appropriately, but it allows the solution quickly & smoothly, so that solves it for me.